# amchart last label on dateAxis is not visible properly

Tags: javascript, axis-labels, gantt-chart, amcharts4

I have an issue when displaying a Gantt chart using the latest amcharts version 4.
Not able to see the last label when the start and end dates are close.
If I use the long duration then I can see the last label on the date axis.

[image]

Date axis properties used below:

```js
    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 70;
    dateAxis.baseInterval = { count: 1, timeUnit: "day" };
    dateAxis.renderer.tooltipLocation = 0;
    dateAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;
    dateAxis.strictMinMax = true;
```

Chart data:

```
data = [ {
  "category": "",
  "start": "2015-03-25",
  "end": "2015-05-09",
  "color": "#1DB329",
  "task": "Active base license"
}, {
  "category": "",
  "start": "2015-05-09",
  "end": "2015-05-24",
  "color": "#FFC048",
  "task": "Warning period"
}];
```

Codepen
https://codepen.io/prashantbiradar92/pen/abpOVap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to see the last label at the edge of the chart, set a `paddingRight` value to an appropriate value so you can see the last label, for example:

```
chart.paddingRight = 50;
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to see the final label, you can adjust the axis' `maxPosition` to hide it as documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/#Start_and_end_labels):

```
dateAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
```